# C#: Is it possible to use expressions or functions as keys in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, caching, dictionary, lambda

Would it work to use `Expression<Func<T>>` or `Func<T>` as keys in a dictionary? For example to cache the result of heavy calculations.

For example, changing my very basic cache from a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131305/c-how-to-implement-a-smart-cache) of mine a bit:

```
public static class Cache<T>
{
    // Alternatively using Expression<Func<T>> instead
    private static Dictionary<Func<T>, T> cache;
    static Cache()
    {
        cache = new Dictionary<Func<T>, T>();
    }
    public static T GetResult(Func<T> f)
    {
        if (cache.ContainsKey(f))
            return cache[f];

       return cache[f] = f();
    }
}
```

Would this even work?

***Edit:*** After a quick test, it seems like it actually works. But I discovered that it could probably be more generic, since it would now be one cache per return type... not sure how to change it so that wouldn't happen though... hmm

***Edit 2:*** Noo, wait... it actually doesn't. Well, for regular methods it does. But not for lambdas. They get various random method names even if they look the same. Oh well c",)

Comment: I'm not. I was just stumbled over the thought while figuring out the cache stuff in my other question and got curious :)

Comment: Bonus points for investigative curiosity, but I can't really see any real application for the technique. On the other hand, the idea does have a high Cool Factor if it would have worked.

Comment: ...Providing the thing would have had a deterministic result, that is.

Comment: Hehe. Non-deterministic results would indeed lower the coolness factor, yes :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any type of object, as long as it is an instance. That even being a delegate, but I do *not* recommend using delegates as keys because they are not designed for that. I'm not sure that independently created delegates produce the same hash code, even less if they can be compared (equatable).

Comment: Seems like you are right about delegates not working well for keys =/

Comment: Delegates compare by reference, not "structurally". That is, two delegates that happen to call the same code but are different instances will compare as unequal.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: So I thought, it is a naturall fallback mechanism when "structure" compares meaningless :)

Comment: I thought delegates that call the same methods on the same classes/instances compare as equal. My limited testing seems to indicate that they do, and Reflector shows "structural" comparison logic in Delegate.Equals...

Answer (score 0):

This might be a stretch, but using the Dynamic Language Runtime (IronPython, etc) you could definitely run arbitrary code snippets from a dictionary.

Then you could run the code on the fly as needed, cache the result the first time, and use the cached result for all future calls.

If you had a lot of computations, I bet this would end up performing pretty well. It's all situational though, and I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve. :)